# Java SSL handshake failure - no client certificate

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I am using a third party library with a build in ssl client to perform a CRL check on a PKCS#7 signature.

I have created a keystore and a truststore and put the server's CA in my truststore.

Looking to the debug below, the Cert Authorities and the Certificate chain are empty. My client didn't send back his certificate.

Could you explain what it's going on?

EDIT

Thanks to the comments below, I understood that the client's "empty CA" is not a problem.

The problem is that the server asks for a client certificate but my client doesn't send it to the server.

Why the client does not send his certificate ?

```
keyStore is : [...]
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : [...]
chain [0] = [
...
]
***
trustStore is: [...]
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
[...]

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[...]
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(10000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1445266954 bytes = { 44, 84, 229, 125, 84, 33, 145, 120, 170, 228, 77, 65, 146, 200, 227, 227, 48, 200, 116, 240, 140, 55, 227, 162, 119, 75, 116, 47 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: ...]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 176
[...]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 176
[Raw write]: length = 181
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 5
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 85
[...]
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 85
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1929314415 bytes = { 133, 174, 213, 209, 239, 104, 185, 151, 182, 150, 87, 234, 171, 201, 244, 45, 171, 118, 159, 20, 148, 138, 19, 5, 1, 44, 188, 76 }
Session ID:  {144, 227, 198, 123, 46, 241, 49, 85, 156, 181, 102, 130, 42, 23, 39, 17, 11, 64, 23, 39, 166, 11, 119, 139, 12, 51, 60, 252, 170, 105, 23, 161}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension server_name, server_name: 
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 85
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 5
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 1024
[...]
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1024
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
 [...]
]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
[...]

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[...]
]
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 1024
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 5
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 8
[...]
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 8
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 8
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 5
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 4
[...]
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
[...]
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 269
[...]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
[Raw write]: length = 274
[...]
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
[...]
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
[...]
Server Nonce:
[...]
Master Secret:
[...]
Client MAC write Secret:
[...]
Server MAC write Secret:
[...]
Client write key:
[...]
Server write key:
[...]
Client write IV:
[...]
Server write IV:
[...]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
[...]
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 212, 27, 4, 13, 87, 128, 70, 120, 43, 97, 111, 135 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
[...]
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 40
[...]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 40
[Raw write]: length = 45
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 5
[...]
[Raw read]: length = 2
[...]
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Comment: I'm surprised something doing CRL check (on PKCS#7 or anything else) is making any SSL/TLS connection. Best practice for CRL fetch and also OCSP is to use plain HTTP, or something else plain like LDAP, to avoid infinite loops. The *data* (CRL or OCSP body) are already signed and don't need further integrity or normally any confidentiality.

Comment: Is there anything in the `Certificate chain` message after `ServerHelloDone` (not sure whether you've removed some lines).

Comment: The certificate chain is empty.

Comment: What's the type of key for the certificate in your keystore? (I'm assuming from your abbreviated output on top that there is indeed a keystore that contains a certificate with its matching private key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the fact that the client's certificate has to be generated by the server via a Certificate Signing Request (CSR).

The process is :

1. Produce a keypair (via keytool -genkey)
2. Generate a PKCS#10 CSR (via keytool -certreq)
3. Send the CSR to the concerned authority
4. Get back a SSL certificate

Thanks for the comments that helped me to improve my ssl understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to throw in my 2 cents on this. I was seeing this exact error in my console log. After much searching and trying out things I finally figured out what the error was. The password was incorrect for my keystore. This error never showed in the logs, it was just silently failing and causing a host of ssl errors to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Client not sending any certificate means 2 things:
1. Server has not requested any certificate (so no CertificateRequest)
2. Server has requested for certificate but your keystore don't have requested certificate.

Answer (score -1):

> the Cert Authorities and the Certificate chain are empty.

That means that the server truststore is empty of trusted CA certificates.

> My client didn't throw back his certificate.

Didn't *send* back his certificate. Exceptions are thrown, not certificates. Don't misuse standard terminology. He's not allowed to send a certificate unless his certificate is trusted by one of the CAs the server said he trusts in the CertificateRequest message.

Comment: But if the server trusts no one, can I still establish a SSL connexion? Is that my problem here?

Comment: I have edited my post to correct my terminology mistake.  Sorry for that.

Comment: If the server trusts no-one, no-one can authenticate via a client certificate. Yet your server is asking for one, and aborting the connection when it doesn't get one. You just have to make up your mind whether you want the client certificate or not, and if so which issuers you are going to trust.

Comment: Empty CAlist doesn't necessarily say anything about server truststore; http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.4 allows server to send an empty list and client to send any cert it wants, and in my testing JSSE client with default SunX509KeyManagerImpl sends the first one it finds for any requested type (algo). I don't know any stack that requests type only RSA as shown here, but if I test with OpenSSL<1.0.0 which doesn't request type ECDSA and my only key is EC(DSA), JSSE does send no cert (empty client-Cert msg). Log shows one key loaded but details elided; probably it isn't RSA.

Comment: The browsers I use (IE, FF, Chrome) if server sends empty CAlist all prompt the user to select a privatekey, if any exist. Obviously if the user, or the code like JSSE, chooses/guesses a cert the server doesn't trust, too bad, so it's *better* if the server does send a CAlist of what it actually wants, but not required.

Comment: Ok, so the server asked my client to send a certificate with no precision about the CA that it trusts. My client didn't send anything, so the server returned an handshake_failure alert. This is it?